Why does memoryless property apply in the first case but not the second?

Marie distributes toys for toddlers. She makes visits to households
and gives away one toy only on visits for which the door is answered
and a toddler is in residence.
On any visit, the probability of the door being answered is 3/4, and
the probability that there is a toddler in residence is 1/3. Assume
that the events “Door answered" and “Toddler in residence" are
independent and also that events related to different households are
independent.

Q1: Given that she has given away her second toy on her fifth visit, what is the conditional probability that she will give away her third toy on her eighth visit?
Q2: Given that she has not given away her second toy by her third visit, what is the conditional probability that she will give away her second toy on her fifth visit?
My question: Why doesn't memoryless property apply in Q2?
The solution given states that the memoryless property applies in Q1 but not Q2. Specifically, let $p=$the probability of door answered and a toddler is present$=1/4$, then the solution to Q1 is just $(1-p)(1-p)p$. I understood this, nothing hard.
But for Q2, the memoryless property does not apply, i.e. let $Y_2=5$ means that the second toy is given on the fifth visit, then $P(Y_2=5|Y_2>3)=\frac{P(Y_2=5\bigcap Y_2>3)}{P(Y_2>3)}$. In other words, this is a straight forward conditional probability calculation and we do take the info given into consideration (i.e. no memoryless property).
I am guessing that because the info given affects our answer, that's why memoryless doesn't apply. But I don't see how.
Is it because in Q1 the info given is related to when a success happened (so the whole process resets and memoryless kicks in), whereas in Q2 the info given does not tell us when a success happened, so the process has still not been reset (so to speak)?
I have also attached the solution below, it came from MITx's 6.431x (in the course it is Q5 not Q2).


Not sure what you are asking.  In any case, the rules are not clear.  It's not enough to say that "door open" and "toddler present" are independent events, you must also assume that knowing that some past  doors have opened or not, or knowing that some past kids have been present or absent, are all independent events.

In any case, the memory-less applies equally well to $Q2$.  the fourth and fifth houses don't "recall" whether prior attempts were successes or failures.  What property, precisely, were you looking at?

@lulu These are all the infos I have been given I am afraid - we are given no info on past doors or kids. For context, this is a chapter on Bernoulli and Poisson process, so I guess the implicit assumption is that this is a never ending sequence of Bernoulli trials. Precisely, I am hoping to understand why the memoryless property does not apply in Q2 (because otherwise it wouldn't be a conditional probability and just a straight forward probability calculation)

Yes, that seems to be the intent, though, as I say, the phrasing is incomplete.

If question 2 had asked for the probability that after three visits, Marie would give away her next toy on her fifth visit, this would be a memoryless process and the probability would be $(1-p)p = 3/16$. Call this scenario A.
If question 2 had asked for the probability that after three visits, Marie would give away two toys in the next two visits, this would be a memoryless process and the probability would be $p^2 = 1/16$. Call this scenario B.
But which scenario gives the correct answer? Neither, as it turns out, because we weren't told how many toys Marie gave away in her first three visits.
If she gave away one toy, scenario A applies.
If she gave away no toys, scenario B applies.
We don't have to worry about any other cases, because we are given that Marie has not yet given away her second toy, but the "memory" that applies is whether Marie has given away her first toy by the third visit.
Given that Marie gave away fewer than two toys in the first three visits, the probability that she has given away one toy is $1/2$ and the probability she has given away no toys is $1/2$. So the overall probability is
$$ \frac12\cdot\frac{3}{16} + \frac12\cdot\frac{1}{16} = \frac18. $$

In Q1 the condition is that the first toy was gifted among the first four visits, and a second on the fifth.  That leaves unknown only where the third gifting occurs after that (we are "starting afresh").
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y_3=8\mid Y_2=5) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y_2=5,Y_3=8)}{\mathsf P(Y_2=5)}\\&= \dfrac{4(1-p)^5p^3}{4(1-p)^3p^2}\\&=(1-p)^2p\end{align}$$
In Q2 the condition does not state whether or not her first toy has been gifted by the third visit; only that she has not gifted the second.  So the condition is that first three visits have had none or just one toy gifted.  Thus we are not "starting afresh".
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y_2=5\mid Y_2>3) &= \dfrac{4(1-p)^3p^2}{(1-p)^3+3(1-p)^2p}\\&=\dfrac{4(1-p)p}{1+2p}\end{align}$$
